# SPOTFIRE: Access Column Names after using $csearch in OVER

Tags: spotfire

The goal is to aggregate columns within a dynamically changing data table.

A datatable (currentOutputTable) is created dynamically when a file is selected from a dropdown within Spotfire.  The table contains information about different properties (P and T), but the number of each property can change depending on the file being read.

```
+------+----+----+-----+----+----+-----+
| Time | P1 | P2 | Pn  | T1 | T2 | Tn  |
+------+----+----+-----+----+----+-----+
|    0 |  0 |  2 | ... | 10 | 15 | ... |
|    1 |  1 |  5 | ... | 12 | 18 | ... |
|    2 |  5 |  5 | ... | 15 | 15 | ... |
|    3 | 10 |  5 | ... | 15 | 20 | ... |
+------+----+----+-----+----+----+-----+
```

For example, I'd like to create a bar graph of the average of each P property.

I was hoping there would be a way I could do something like the following using `$csearch`, but haven't been able to figure it out.

```
Avg([Column from OVER])
OVER
$esc($csearch([currentOutputTable],"P*"))
```

The closest I've gotten is using

```
$esc($csearch([currentOutputTable],"P*"))
```

and trellis or category by column name, but obviously this doesn't give the average.

Essentially I want to plot only the average of each individual P parameter

```
(Avg(["P1"]), Avg(["P2"], ... , Avg(["Pn"]) )
```

I hope this makes sense and thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know ahead of time the number of properties that will return based on their dropdown selection? Could you on the fly dynamically edit the formula as well?

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t know a head of time the number of properties that are within the file. There may be 5 P columns in one file and 10 in another.

Comment: If I did would that help?  I ask because if this is critical to the solution I may be able to change the files or other data tables that contain information about the files.

Comment: If I understand correctly... If you know what file the user wants to load (which it sounds like you already do), and if you knew how many parameters were in that file, then could you just write out custom formulas to a document property and use that document property as the bar graph formula? The formula would vary in length depending on the file selected.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily IronPython is here to save the day!

Trigger the script after the table has been refreshed, and loop through all the columns in your data table, checking to see if the column name starts with "P".  If it does, add the average of the column to a string, that you put into a new property (I named it "SelectedColumns" here).  This property can then be thrown where you wanted that pesky list of Avg(["P1"]), Avg(["P2"], ... , Avg(["Pn"])

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *
from System import DateTime 
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataType import Date 


myDocument=Application.Document      

if myDocument.Data.Tables.Contains("currentOutputTable")==True:
   myTable=myDocument.Data.Tables["currentOutputTable"]     

x = ""
for col in myTable.Columns: 
    #print col.Properties["ExternalName"] 
    #print col.Properties["Name"]
    if col.Properties["Name"][0] == "P":
        x+= 'Avg(["' + col.Properties["Name"] + '"]), '

#print x[0:len(x)- 2]       
Document.Properties["SelectedColumns"] = x[0:len(x)- 2]
```